# How to call C function received as an argument

Tags: c, go, cross-language

I want to use Go library with some adjusted in C.
I made GoAdder Go function that having 3 arguments int x, y and function typed f.

And GoAdder function going to call f argument.

**adder.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

import "C" 

//export Ftest
type Ftest func(C.int);

//export GoAdder
func GoAdder(x, y int, f Ftest) int {
    fmt.Printf("Go says: adding %v and %v\n", x, y) 
    f(10); 

    return x + y
}

func main() {} // Required but ignored
```

And I built go package as a static library named libadder.a in above like this:

`go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libadder.a adder.go`

And then I have written C++ codes bellow.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "adder/libadder.h"

void a( GoInt a ){
  printf("Hello %d", a);
}

int main() {
  printf("C says: about to call Go...\n");
  int total = GoAdder(1, 7, &a);
  printf("C says: Go calculated our total as %i\n", total);
  return 0;
}
```

I have complied the source like this:

`gcc -pthread -o static_go_lib main.c adder/libadder.a`

when executing codes above it occurs errors

```
unexpected fault address 0x0
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x563c99b74244]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
...
```

How to get a correct C function address **a** in go function **GoAdder** ?

I referenced https://github.com/draffensperger/go-interlang/tree/master/c_to_go/static_go_lib

Comment: @TedLyngmo I used this `go build -buildmode=c-archive -o libadder.a`

Comment: Ok, I added that to the question, but you can modify/edit your question yourself by using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57735683/edit) link.

Comment: You're welcome, but I still don't have information enough to reproduce the problem myself. `adder/libadder.h` becomes `libadder.h` but even with that change in your `.cpp` file, compilation fails: Command: `g++ useadder.cpp -o useadder -L. -ladder -lpthread` gives: `error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(GoInt)’ {aka ‘void (*)(long long int)’} to ‘void*’`. You need to supply more info and/or correct that error.

Comment: I actually think that by-passing the above compilation issue is what causes your problem. By allowing the above violation (`-fpermissive`) I get the same error as you do. Don't use `-fpermissive`, correct the code - and you're done.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, here is my full source code. https://github.com/skyend/call_callback_c_func_in_go you can run by just make command.

Comment: I'm trying to help you to update the actual question so that it's self-contained so that people who knows this stuff (I don't) will get intrigued and help out. A good question does not require people to download a project from anywhere. Put what's needed in the question. Create a [mcve] and it's more likely that people who do C/Go stuff will jump at it.

Comment: Btw, I just noticed that this is tagged `c++`. Why not `C`?

Comment: Suggestion: Change the top `Makefile`: `CCFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -pthread` should help.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, I have understood what you hope and what you want direction. I am sorry. I wanted this problem have got solved faster. but I was doing with the wrong way. Thank you for your help. i will update my question with more information.

Comment: Use the flags I gave when compiling the C code: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -pthread -o static_go_lib main.c adder/libadder.a` and fix the error you get. I don't think it should be necessary to violate the C language to be able to link to a library written in Go (although, I'm not certain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C function is just jump pointer, whereas golang's callback are complicate struct, and you cannot convert them. 
There's only one (safe) way to call C function pointer:
1) Declare that somewhere:

```golang
//go:linkname cgocall runtime.cgocall
//go:nosplit
func cgocall(fn, arg unsafe.Pointer /* may be uintptr */) int32
```

2) Also, be type safe:

```golang
func GoAdder(x, y C.int, f unsafe.Pointer /*  don't sure if this available, mb C.uintptr_t */) C.int
```

3) C function should take pointer (to what ever) as argument

```c
void a(GoInt *a)
```

(I'd use native types)

4)

```golang
ten := 10
cgocall(f, unsafe.Pointer(&ten))
```

(It should be struct, if you wanna pass several args)